# CALayer on top of UIView Hierachy iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, calayer, uiviewanimation, caanimation

trying to update my app in iOS 7, i have a problem using UIVIew animation

I have a UIScrollView in which i have a UIView when the user touch the view i convert the UIView position into its superview container (the main view self.view) then i add an animation on this UIView.

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:aView cache:YES];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

But on iOS 7 the animation cut the view and the animation is clearly messed up. So i decided to use a CABasicAnimation on my UIView :

```
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2 * M_PI];
rotationAnimation.duration = 0.6;
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
aView.layer.zPosition = 400;
[aBigView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation1"];
```

The animation is ok, nevertheless after this animation i add my custom AlertView using :

```
[self.view addSubview:myAlertView];
```

When i use the basic Animation my custom alertView appears below the UIview, i tried to use insertSubview:belowSubView, but didn't work, i know it is because i use CALAyer, but i couldn't find a way to add my alertview above this UIView layer...

Can someone help me ?

Thank you very much !